# writing binary data in R

Tags: r, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write an HTTP POST request, but I need to get my data into binary format first. This is probably an easy question, but I find R connections really confusing, and I've been having trouble finding a good resource that explains them in a way I understand.

So as an example, say I want to encode an integer (8 byte) and then a numeric (4 byte). Here is the code I've tried:

```
myint <- as.integer(1339700942)
mydouble <- 1.2
obj <- file(open='w+b') #I've tried textConnection too, but no good
w.int <- writeBin(myint, obj, size=8, endian='big')
w.double <- writeBin(mydouble, obj, size=4, endian='big')
```

This allowed me to open the connection, but all it wrote was `NULL`. What is the correct way to use connections and `writeBin` in a situation like this?

Comment: Thanks Joshua! My mistake with the variable names.

Comment: According to `?writeBin` it returns `NULL` unless the `con` argument is a raw vector, which it is not in your example.  It would help if you could give more background on your actual problem.

Comment: The example is very close to my actual problem. I want to post XDR data onto a website, and the format will be a repeating sequence of 8-byte ints and 4-byte floats.

Comment: should I assign 'obj <- raw(0)' instead of opening a connection...?

Comment: I'm really glad you figured out your problem! Would you please write an answer summarizing what worked for you and (after the mandatory waiting period) accept it? That way it's more likely that other people will benefit from what you learned. (As an added incentive, I will check back and up vote your answer...)

Comment: Sure! I wanted to give @Joshua or others a chance to answer it first... I thought he deserved the rep more since his note led me to the answer.

Comment: No worries @LizSander. You can see that I'm not in need of points. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object 'obj' is not actually necessary. If writeBin is writing to an R object rather than a file outside of R, the last three lines can be replaced by:

```
w.int <- writeBin(myint, raw(0), size=8, endian='big')
w.double <- writeBin(mydouble, raw(0), size=4, endian='big')
```